# how to open pdf in webview without gdoc from Url

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I try to open pdf url in my webview with below code , i found solutions with gdoc but it is not useful for me because I want to show pdf only in view mode and user should not download and also need to clear cache after back press

code :

```
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(false);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    settings.setSaveFormData(false);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.addView(webView.getZoomControls());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=**PDFurl**");
```

also, add permission in manifest as it needs internet connectivity (must required)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

this will work!

if direct url not work then lode this

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.loadUrl(pdf);
```

also,

```
String pdf="<iframe src='http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=+location to your PDF File+' 
          width='100%' height='100%' 
          style='border: none;'></iframe>";
```

Comment: what is in MyWebViewClient()

Comment: mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true) not work

Comment: I want to use some methods so i called it.. checkout this link :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html